# SQL Query Error: Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'Enrollment.final_grade' in 'having clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am tying to find "For each prof that taught the same class, find the number of students that dropped before the drop deadline ("W" grade) but I keep getting an error about my HAVING clause. Can someone point me to the right direction? No table is even forming. I'm assuming I need a SELECT somewhere else as well before HAVING? Please explain what I'm missing or messed up on, thank you!

```
CREATE TABLE Student (
  student_id INT(9) PRIMARY KEY, 
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
  gpa DECIMAL(3,2) DEFAULT 0.00
);

CREATE TABLE Course (
  course_id CHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY, 
  description VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
  units INT DEFAULT 3
);

CREATE TABLE CourseSection (
  course CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  section INT(1) DEFAULT 1,
  CONSTRAINT FK_SECTION_COURSE FOREIGN KEY (course) REFERENCES Course(course_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE CoursePrerequisites ( 
  course CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  prerequisite CHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT FK_COURSEPREREQUISITES_COURSE FOREIGN KEY (course) REFERENCES Course(course_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
  CONSTRAINT FK_COURSEPREREQUISITES_PREREQUISITES FOREIGN KEY (prerequisite) REFERENCES Course(course_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);


CREATE TABLE Faculty (
  faculty_id INT(9) PRIMARY KEY, 
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
  role ENUM ('professor','researcher','both')
);


CREATE TABLE Application (
  application_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  student INT(9) NOT NULL, 
  program ENUM('Phd', 'Master', 'Undergrad'),
  department ENUM("CS", "MATH"),
  status ENUM("Admitted", "Rejected") DEFAULT "Rejected",
  CONSTRAINT FK_APPLICATION_STUDENT FOREIGN KEY (student) REFERENCES Student(student_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
  
);

CREATE TABLE Enrollment (
  enrollment_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  course CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  student INT(9) NOT NULL,
  date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  semester ENUM('FA', 'SP', 'SU'), 
  status ENUM('dropped', 'enrolled') DEFAULT "enrolled",
  final_grade ENUM('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'NC', 'IC', 'CR', 'W', 'WU', 'NA') DEFAULT 'A',
  CONSTRAINT FK_ENROLLMENT_COURSE FOREIGN KEY (course) REFERENCES Course(course_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
  CONSTRAINT FK_ENROLLMENT_STUDENT FOREIGN KEY (student) REFERENCES Student(student_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE 
);
```

```
SELECT Course.course_id, Student.student_id, COUNT(Enrollment.final_grade) 
FROM Enrollment
JOIN Course ON Course.course_id = Enrollment.course
JOIN Student ON Student.student_id = Enrollment.student
GROUP BY Course.course_id
HAVING Enrollment.final_grade = 'W';
```

Comment: The condition by the table-source must be placed in WHERE. And, when the column is present in the output list not as aggregate function argument, it must be included into the  grouping expression.

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY need Student.student_id field.

```sql
SELECT Course.course_id, Student.student_id, COUNT(Enrollment.final_grade) 
FROM Enrollment
JOIN Course ON Course.course_id = Enrollment.course
JOIN Student ON Student.student_id = Enrollment.student
WHERE Enrollment.final_grade = 'W'
GROUP BY Course.course_id, Student.student_id;
```

Comment: Thank you! The GROUP BY makes sense now after some testing with what you wrote. If I have something in SELECT, it has to be in the GROUP BY it seems.